# ¿Como agregar usuarios a diferentes grupos sin usar el Admin de Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

¿Cómo puedo agregar usuarios a diferentes grupos sin usar el administrador? Entiendo que tengo tres tipos de usuarios que eligen el tipo que desean ser en el momento del registro. Ya tengo los grupos creados con los diferentes permisos. Mi pregunta es: Cuando creo los usuarios a través de la placa de registro, también los agrego al grupo que le corresponde.

esto es lo que se ha comprobado hasta ahora:

model.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    profesion=models.ForeignKey(Profesion,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,null=True)
    pais=models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=False,null=True)

    is_free=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_basic=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_premium=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        permissions=(("modificar_cada_onda","Permite modifcar cada onda"),
                     ("modificar_cada_intervalo","Permite modificar cada intervao"),
                     ("acceso_al_contenido_por_onda","Da acceso al contenido por onda"),
                     ("acceso_al_contenido_por_intervalo","Da acceso al contenido por intervalo"),
                     ("acceso_al_contenido_de_las_arritmias","Acceso al contenido de las Arritmias"),
                     ("50_ekg_generados_x_mes","50 EKG generados x mes"),
                     ("diagnosticos_por_ia","Diagnosticos x IA(100 x mes)"),
```

views.py

```
class FreeSignUpView(CreateView):
    model=CustomUser
    form_class = FreeSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def  get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type']='free'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user=form.save()
        login(self.request,user)
        return redirect('free_signup')
```

forms.py

```
class FreeSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    pais = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Pais.objects.all())
    anno = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profesion.objects.all())

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model=CustomUser
        fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name',)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        qs = CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("La direccion email ya existe")
        return email


    @transaction.atomic()
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user=super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_free=True

      #el error ocurre cuando intento agregar el usuario al grupo
        group=Group.objects.get(name='free')
        group.user_set.add(user)

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

me lanza el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que sucede es que estás intentando agregar el `CustomUser` y no el `User` que es el modelo al cual en realidad tiene relación. Dentro de tu `CustomUser` deberías tener una relación con la tabla `User` y hacer la relación por medio de este campo. Es decir, suponiendo que el campo de la relación se llama `usuario`, entonces te quedaría así: `grupo.user_set.add(user.usuario)`

Comment: edite mi pregunta e puesto el modelo, utilice AbstractUser para poder agregarle campos  al usuario por defecto que brinda Django.

Answer (score 0):

yo no soy ningun experto en django ,pero esto es lo que uso yo:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        group = Group.objects.get(name='empresa')
        user.groups.add(group)
        return redirect('/influ/')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
return render(request, 'agenda24/registro.html', {'form': form})
```

espero que te sirva un saludo.